# xsl asp.net open source projct

Tags: asp.net, xslt, open-source, frameworks

can any one indicate a asp.net open source project based on xsl?
Thanx.

Comment: XSL is Extensible Stylesheet Language, not sure how you think a site might be based XSL. What do you mean by 'based on XSL'?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you need open source projects which manage presentation using xml, xsl and xslt...
There are some projects available in [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/)

### [AspXslt](http://aspxslt.codeplex.com/)

> AspXslt is an easy way of separating presentation layer from business logic by using an HttpHandler to transform XML documents generated by your custom components. It can be the foundation of a bigger project like a CMS or MVC application.
>   It's developed in C#.

### [Landscape - XSL Presentation Framework](http://lsc.codeplex.com/)

> Landscape is a flexible presentation framework for ASP.NET web applications written in C# and based on the XSLT language.
>
> It is meant to take care of all the operation necessary to produce well-formed, clean and reusable (X)HTML code.
>
> It currently supports the following features:
>
> - Nestable templates
> - Template2Template parameters
> - Custom reusable presentation code definition (widgets)
> - XSLT template caching
> - An XSLT Extension providing a very basic (for now!) set of function for use into XSLT templates